# If $\omega$ is an imaginary cube root of $1$, then $(1+\omega-\omega^2)^5+(1-\omega+\omega^2)^5=$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am pretty stuck, can't seem to arrive at an answer

Comment: Please try and use $\LaTeX$, see the edit that has kindly been done by @JoeJohnson.

Comment: I guess $\omega$ isn't imaginary, it's only nonreal (imaginary = pure imaginary).

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$\omega^3=1$  and as  $\omega\ne1,1+\omega+\omega^2=\dfrac{\omega^3-1}{\omega-1}=0$

$$\implies 1+\omega=-\omega^2,1+\omega^2=-\omega, \omega+\omega^2=-1$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $1+\omega +\omega^2=0$

So, $1+\omega-\omega^2=-2\omega^2$ and $1-\omega+\omega^2=-2\omega$

So $(-2\omega^2)^5+(-2\omega)^5=-32\omega-32\omega^2=32$

Comment: Lone Wolf,  Nice answer +1. It was very easy.